# How to download docx file rather than loading file in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

Firefox tries to read docx files rather than download them:

```
<a href="app/files/resources/downloads/Sample_Revision_Sheet.docx"
   target="_blank"> 
   Sample_Revision_Sheet.docx
</a>
```

Comment: `.zip` fallback maybe? not ideal though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute, introduced in HTML5:

> This attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the
>   hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource so that when the user
>   clicks on the link they will be prompted to save it as a local file.
>   If the attribute has a value, the value will be used as the pre-filled
>   file name in the Save prompt that opens when the user clicks on the
>   link.

```html
<a href="app/files/resources/downloads/Sample_Revision_Sheet.docx"
   download="Sample_Revision_Sheet.docx"> 
   Sample_Revision_Sheet.docx
</a>
```